# Xamarin forms for desktop

Tags: c#, xamarin

Нужно разработать мультиплатформенное десктопное(в будущем возможно и мобила) приложение. Выбрал Xamarin Forms, он только для мобильных приложений? или можно создать нормальное десковое приложение?

Comment: Да, только для мобильных. Для десктопных есть WPF или Windows Forms.

Comment: просто, xamarin forms поддерживает  UWP и WPF. Разве этотого не достаточно для создания десктопа?

Comment: На текущий момент все настолки у них в статусе `Preview`. Вообще для настолок есть альтернативы.

Comment: @Vasek Какие альтернативы?

Comment: [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) или [Avalonia](http://avaloniaui.net/) - пока только бета.